# Dynamically added linkbutton click doesn't fire (init only??) , updatepanel and triggers

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, triggers

When the user selects an "account" we dynamically create a linkbutton with the selected dates.

However, the linkbutton onclick handler doesn't fire when the button is clicked.

thx

```
Dim linkBtn As New LinkButton
linkBtn.Text = "blah"
AddHandler linkBtn.Click, AddressOf linkButtonHandler
linkBtn.ID = panelDatesRencontre.Controls.OfType(Of LinkButton).Count
panelDatesRencontre.Controls.Add(linkBtn)
ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(linkBtn)

Dim Trigger1 As New AsyncPostBackTrigger
Trigger1.ControlID = linkBtn.ID
Trigger1.EventName = "Click"
UpdatePanel2.Triggers.Add(Trigger1)
```

Answer: i make that in page_load, it seems to work

Comment: Where and when do you add the linkbutton dynamically? **Do you recreate it on every Postback in Page_Init?** Is the ID of the control the same after postback?

Answer (score 1):

In order for the handler to be available it has to be recreated in the page_init section.

Otherwise you'll just get a postback without the handler executing.